# Update minified CSS in ASP.NET Core on OS X

Tags: css, asp.net-core, updates, bundling-and-minification, rider

I have a simpe ASP.NET Core site built on the default template. **I need to have the site.min.css updated since site.css has been updated.**

This is on OS X in Jetbrains Rider. The MSDN docs say that (on Windows!) simply rebuilding the project would update the minified files.

the bundleconfig.json file is unchanged:

```
// Configure bundling and minification for the project.
// More info at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808241
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    // An array of relative input file paths. Globbing patterns supported
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optionally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

*How can I update the minified file(s) be it from the IDE or the CLI (Command Line Interface)?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for a long delay. I was preparing to the conference. For fix your problem just add: `<PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.4.337" />` to you csproj file. And you bundle files would be updated after build.